# Spring parse String to enum before entering the controller

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have the following controller:

```
public interface SaveController {
  @PostMapping(value = "/save")
  @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
  void save(@RequestBody @Valid SaveRequest saveRequest);
}
```

`SaveRequest` corresponds to:

```
public class SaveRequest {
  @NotNull
  private SaveType type;

  private String name;
}
```

and `SaveType`:

```
public enum SaveType {
  DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY;
}
```

The controller does not receive the `enum` itself, but a camelCase `String`. I need to convert that `String` into the corresponding `enum`. For instance:

- `daily` should become `DAILY`.
- `weekly` should become `WEEKLY`.
- `monthly` should become `MONTHLY`.
- Any other `String` should become `null`.

I've tried using the Spring `Converter` class, which does not work when the `enum` is inside an object (at least I don't know how to make it work in such times).

I honestly don't know what else to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums
This site should probably give you plenty of options.

Best is probably something like this:

```
public enum SaveType {
    
    DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY;

    @JsonCreator
    public static SaveType saveTypeforValue(String value) {
        return SaveType.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you require is to have custom annotation with a custom validation class for Enum.

`javax.validation` library doesn't have inbuilt support for enums.

Validation class

```java
public class SaveTypeSubSetValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SaveTypeSubset, SaveType> {
    private SaveType[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(SaveTypeSubset constraint) {
        this.subset = constraint.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(SaveType value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }
}
```

interface for validation annotation with validation message

```java
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = SaveTypeSubSetValidator.class)
public @interface SaveTypeSubset {
    SaveType[] anyOf();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Usage

```java
@SaveTypeSubset(anyOf = {SaveType.NEW, SaveType.OLD})
private SaveType SaveType;
```

This is one way. More ways are mentioned in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums).

Comment: Validation isn't going to help in the conversion.